# When is the limit definition of a partial derivative more appropriate?

Tags: calculus

I was posed the following problem the other day:

Find $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}$, where:
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{(a-t)(s-b)}{a-b} & a\le t\le s \le b\\
\frac{(a-s)(t-b)}{a-b} & a\le s\le t \le b
\end{cases}
$$

At first glance it seems like it should be equal to zero for all t and s in their appropriate domains, but in this case it is supposed to be $\frac{-1}{a-b}$ when $s=t$. This is derived using the limit definition of the partial derivative for the first derivative.

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(t+h,t) - f(t,t)}{h}
$$

Normal methods then work for the second partial derivative.

My question is: is there anything 'obvious' about $f(x)$ that would suggest such non-intuitive behavior? (Or maybe there is something inappropriate about this approach?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "obvious" red flag is the piecewise definition. We know full well that piecewise definitions create unexpected behavior even just for the derivative of real functions of a real variable, starting from the absolute value function which is everywhere continuous but not differentiable at $0$, and continuing with other even odder behaviors.

Your "at first glance" judgement is appropriate for all $s,t$ in **the interior of** their appropriate domains, i.e. in $t < s$ for the first formula and in $t > s$ for the second formula. But when the two pieces of the formula meet along the line $t=s$, all bets are off.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the response.